# How to dynamically pass a variable to a 3rd party tracking pixel

Tags: javascript, client-side-scripting

Here is what I'm dealing with. I require a way to dynamically pass a variable or value (sale amount and order id) to a 3rd party tracking pixel for my cost per sale campaign as I am using affiliate marketing. I cannot get help from Intuit who I used to design and host my site. My affiliate marketing support sent this... Just tell them you need to “dynamically pass sale amount and order ID through a 3rd party tracking pixel.”  They should come back with a syntax for you to add to the code.  It might be something like `<order.number>`  or `“<orderamount>”` . . . . So basically, I have the code on the confirmation page, but don't know how to dynamically pass the amount and order id so that the proper commission can be paid. Please help. Thanks. :confused:

Here is the code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://www.linkconnector.com/tmjs.php?lc=000000002852&oid=&amt="></script>
```

Comment: Tracking pixels? Do you mean tracking *cookie* ?

Comment: Do you have access to the order amount and id in the query string i.e. does the URL for the confirmation page have ?orderid=xxx&amt=xxx on the end of it?

Comment: @Seth, tracking pixel is (usually) a transparent 1x1 pixel image, placed on the bottom of the page. The 3rd-party serves the pixel through a server-side script, PHP in this case. It allows the 3rd-party to keep statistics.

Comment: What technology is your site written in? ASP.NET? php? Your page needs to have knowledge of the order id and amount before the content is rendered to the browser.

Comment: @Seth - maybe the javascript dynamically creates an image. @Justin - I know that Intuit is an extremely cheap hosting service (I know because they spam me all the time about it). My advice: pay a little more for one that has real customer service.

Comment: An HTTP request which fetches a 1x1 transparent gif will involve header exchange which may generate cookies. But the "pixel" itself doesn't do any tracking. If "tracking pixel" is a common term being used to describe this, then put a stop to it. It's misleading (maybe on purpose). I'm imagining someone asking for a way to "turn off pixels" or "block pixels."

Answer (score 0):

Did they pass this exact structure to you ?

When you finish your transaction, from where do you have access to the order ID and amount ?
If you access those variable via PHP, you just have to include the URL contained in your structure with the proper variables.
If you access those variable via JavaScript, you might insert a 1x1 transparent image with the src set to this URL, with proper variables...

Does that help you ? If not please specify how do you access your parameters.

Comment: <script language="JavaScript" src="https://www.linkconnector.com/tmjs.php?lc=000000002852&confirmationnumber=$invoice.confirmationNumber&ordersubtotal=$invoice.orderSubtotal"><ss:param name="confirmationnumber" value="$invoice.confirmationNumber"/><ss:value source="$invoice.confirmationNumber"/><ss:param name="ordersubtotal" value="$invoice.orderSubtotal"/><ss:value source="$invoice.orderSubtotal"/></script><noscript><img border="0" src="https://linkconnector.com/tm.php?lc=000000002852&oid=&amt="></noscript>

Comment: This is some code that may work. I basically just added the syntax from the page that gives a confirmation number. I'm not sure if this even correct, but it's at least more than I started with. First, I had to find a way add confirmation number and order subtotal to the URL line and then also defined the parameters and values. I'm still a bit lost, but gaining a little.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to pass the value by using Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `document.write`

```
    var MyLC = put your LC here;var MyOID = put your OID here;var MyAMT = put your amount here;
    document.write(" <scr"+"ipt src=\"\/\/www.linkconnector.com/tmjs.php?lc="+MyLC+"&oid="+MyOID+"&amt="+MyAMT+"\"><\/script>");
```

Put this in an `<iframe>`, so that the loading of the script doesn't hold up the loading of the rest of the page. (When the external server times out, for example)